# Rails: configuring applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am reading and coding along with a tutorial.

I have an application.yml file with some constants created to hold data. To include those constants in ENV and initialize them at start, this code was given :

```
config_file = Rails.application.config_for(:application) #this is the bothersome part
config_file.each do |key,value|
ENV[key] = value
end unless config_file.nil?
```

I fail to fully understand this code. In particular, on the first line, where do the chained objects come from what do they mean and how do I create such on my own ?

Answer (score 0):

It loads data from a config file into the app. The example from the [docs about `#config_for`](https://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Application/config_for):

```
#config/app.yml:
production:
  url: http://127.0.0.1:8080
  namespace: my_app_production
development:
  url: http://localhost:3001
  namespace: my_app_development
```

If you do `rails c` and type `Rails.application.config_for(:app)` into the console, you'll get:

```
 {"url"=>"http://localhost:3001", "namespace"=>"my_app_development"}
```

which is just a regular hash you can loop through using `#each` or access it's values through keys.